# functional way to go through series of validation in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have some data that need to go through a series a validations. I have the following Java style code that works, but seems ugly. Just wondering what would be the functional / Scala way to handle such situations? Thanks!

```
def validateData(data: String): Boolean = {
  try {
    if(!validate1(data)) {
      Logger.error("error1")
      return false
    }
    if(!validate2(data)) {
      Logger.error("error2")
      return false
    }
    if(!validate3(data)) {
      Logger.error("error3")
      return false
    }
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => {
      Logger.error(e.getMessage)
      return false
    }
  }
  true
}
```

Comment: Good read regarding error handling: http://longcao.org/2015/06/15/easing-into-functional-error-handling-in-scala

Comment: @NathanHughes台湾不在中国 then how about the error logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`cats.data.ValidatedNel`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html) (which in an alias for `Validated[NonEmptyList[E], A]`), which is an exact fit for this kind of validation:

```
import cats.data.ValidatedNel
import cats.implicits._

def validation(data: String): Validated[NonEmptyList[String], Boolean] = {

  def validateData1(data: String): ValidatedNel[String, Unit] = ???

  def validateData2(data: String): ValidatedNel[String, Unit] = ???

  def validateData3(data: String): ValidatedNel[String, Unit] = ???

  val data: String = ???

  val res: ValidatedNel[String, Unit] =
    validateData1(data) *>
      validateData2(data) *>
      validateData3(data)

  res.map(_ => true)
}
```

And then:

```
validation("foo").toEither match {
  case Left(errors) => // log errors
  case Right(validation) => // Do whatever you want with the validated boolean
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Try` like below:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def validateData(data: String): Boolean = {
  def logErr(valid: Boolean, e: String): Boolean =
    if (valid) true else {
        Logger.error(e)
        false
      }

  Try(logErr(validate1(data), "error1") && 
      logErr(validate2(data), "error2") && 
      logErr(validate3(data), "error3")
    ) match {
      case Success(res) => res
      case Failure(ex)  =>
        Logger.error(ex)
        false
    }
}
```